# Makefile not detecting changes in header file?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have the following MakeFile:

```
TARGET = target
CC = gcc-9
CFLAGS = -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wvla -Wextra -Wundef -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 
OBJ = dep1.o $(TARGET).o dep2.o

all: $(TARGET)

run: $(TARGET)
    ./$<

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

$(TARGET).o: $(TARGET).c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^

dep1.o: dep1.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^

dep2.o: dep2.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $^

dep1.c: dep1.h
$(TARGET).c: dep1.h

clean:
    rm -rfv $(TARGET) *.o *.a *.dylib *.dSYM
```

When `dep1.h` changes, I want to be able to recompile with the new changes involved. `dep1.c` includes `dep1.h`. `$(TARGET)` also includes `dep1.h`

I have tried several other solutions online, but none of really seemed to work. The only way I was able to get it to work was by changing `all: clean $(TARGET)`. By doing so, the project would get cleaned first, and then it would recompile with the new changes in `dep1.h`, but I feel like that is a really hacky solution and there is a better way, but I am not sure.

Comment: In addition to the answer below note that your statement _`$(TARGET)` also includes `dep1.h`_ is not correct: `$(TARGET)` is a program and it is created by linking object files together: linking object files together doesn't include header files.  Header files are included ONLY by the compiler, when it creates object files from source files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
dep1.c: dep1.h
$(TARGET).c: dep1.h
```

The C files do not depend on the H files. Saying that the C files depend on the H files would mean that you use the H files to create the C files. Actually, it is the object files which depend on both the H and C files.

```
dep1.o: dep1.c dep1.h
```

This is the manual way to write it. You do not need to write the rule, the implicit rule is fine, but the correct way to write an explicit rule for this requires using `$<` instead of `$^`, because `$^` includes all dependencies (including the header files). The `$<` variable only includes the first input, so you have to write the C file first in the dependencies.

```
dep1.o: dep1.c dep1.h
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $<
```

There are ways to handle this automatically using the `-M` flags, if your compiler supports them (GCC does, and many other compilers support them in a compatible way).

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Was driving me nuts, but this makes a lot more sense now. Thank you so much for the explanation. Will accept answer once it's off cool down.

Comment: No problem—you probably also know this, but it is easy to accidentally make a mistake when writing a makefile, and this can sometimes result in hours wasted in debugging. This is why people use makefile generators or use newer build systems.

Comment: Yes, I was aware of this, my IDE has something built in for me so I didn't have to write it on my own, but I wanted to learn this since I still see it everywhere in GHub Repos. Thank you for the advice and letting me know.

Comment: A really good reference for autogenerating dependencies is here: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/   If you want to write makefiles for larger projects, knowing this is very useful.